# How to allocate non-paged memory under Windows

Tags: windows, winapi

When I use cudaHostAlloc() it will allocate non-paged ( pinned, page-locked ) memory. I'm wondering how I can do that without cuda by just using Windows SDK?

Comment: Memory you allocate using `malloc()` or `LocalAlloc()` with the `LMEM_FIXED` flag will be at fixed addresses, they don't need to be locked before you use them. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Non-paged memory is guaranteed to stay in the memory. It will not be swapped out by the OS. Does the parameter LMEM_FIXED do that?

Comment: Ah ok, no, but I think you can use `VirtualAlloc` followed by `VirtualLock` to do that.

Comment: Thanks! That could be it. But according to some msdn blog the memory manager only guarantees the memory block wont be paged out whenever there is an executing thread in the process. Meaning if all threads are blocked the memory could be swapped out. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/11/06/5924058.aspx

Comment: I guess your best option if you really want to prevent paging is, as the blog says, "grant your process the SeLockMemoryPrivilege privilege and use the AWE functions to allocate non-pageable memory" - e.g. `AllocateUserPhysicalPages`.

Comment: Cool. Thanks a lot! You have been very helpful!

Comment: @chhenning: that was a mistake, see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2014/02/07/10497475.aspx