# How to force an application to use memory instead of the page file?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, windows-8.1

I'm not sure if that's even a proper question, but is there any way to "force" an application to use the phyiscal memory instead of the page file?

To be more exact: I wrote an application (C++) to analyze some measurement data. Therefore, it needs to allocate a pretty huge array which makes the process use about 12 GB of RAM. I do have 16 GB installed, so that should not be too much of a problem. I started the programm, it filled my RAM (until there's been about 1GB left). I did continue to use my laptop for a while and just let it run over night afterwards.
Looking at my programm in the morning after, it was only about 25% done when it should actually be at more than 80% after that time. Looking in the task manager, I can see, that it's only using about 1.8 GB of RAM instead of the 12 GB it used before. The so called "commit" is filled with 23 / 31.9 GB.

So, my physical memory seems to be almost empty (there's been more than 12 GB available) and the programm keeps on running really slow. If that's even the reason for it to run that slow: is there a way to force it to use the physical memory?
Also, the .exe is shown as "background service" in the task manager. When starting a new instance, it's shown as an application. May this cause memory restrictions?

EDIT: Running on Windows 8.1 x64.

Comment: It usually depends on the Operating System. You should add an OS specific tag.

Comment: the brute-force approach is to reduce the virtual memory in the system settings ... and hope that "the rest" still works properly :-)

Comment: That would happen if the program wasn't actually accessing the pages concerned. Unless you are seeing a lot of paging activity I think you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: if you're compiling your code for Win32, there is a hard 2Gb limit per process (32 bits make for a 4Gb address space and half of it is reserved for kernel virtual addresses). Recompiling for x64 might help.

Comment: For very huge arrays, I've heard that `std::deque` can offer better performance.

Comment: @kuroineko It is compiled for x64.

Comment: You'll want to allocate nonpaged memory. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17892358/how-to-allocate-non-paged-memory-under-windows

Comment: VirtualLock will hold pages in physical memory, but it isn't really intended for huge allocations; you might find that there is a limit to how large a working set size you can configure.

Comment: You should also check the power management settings; Windows might have decided to save power by ramping down the CPU speed.

Comment: There is always the solution to disable page file (and power savings). At your own risk, of course. I still use Win7, so I can't say if this is still possible in 8.1 but I suppose it is.

Comment: @EJP There have been about 14,000,000 page faults over the last 35 hours of the process running. Is that the number I'm looking for and if so, is that a big one?

Completely fixing the physical memory seems to introduce new problems. I guess I was "dreaming" of a way to make the application re-use physical memory when there is some available while still using paging when it's needed. At the moment, it seems to "give up" its memory due to more important processes but to never reclaim it after those more important tasks are done.

Comment: 14M page-faults in 35 hours is not a majory concern - it's 111 pagefaults per second, which I'm pretty sure is below the average for a windows application (considering there is a page-fault for just about every page of the program and all DLL's it uses, for example).

Comment: In your "test that allocates lots of memory", do you actually "do" something with the memory [write to it, read from it]? If no, I expect the exact behaviour you describe, that it doesn't actually take any space in RAM, because it's just reserved space, not actually used.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I do use `.push_back(0)` to fill the array with zeros. After that, I read in a file to fill the array with the values to analyse afterwards (not every cell will be filled, it is important to have those zeros in the "empty" ones).

Comment: Why not populate the vecotr at construction:  `vector<int> v(huge_size, 0);`   ?   With all these `push_back()`, I bet that it spents an awful lot of time reallocating the array each time it grows...

Comment: @Christophe Yeah, I know. I just started coding in C++ when I decided to solve it this way. It would mean a lot of effort to redo the array structure to be one dimensional with proper indication. I would probably not even use vectors for that specific problem, if I were to redo the coding from scratch..

Answer (score 0):

BYTE* buf = (BYTE*)GlobalAlloc(GMEM_FIXED | GMEM_ZEROINIT, size_buffer);

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.